# AWS vs Dedicated server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am hosting a low traffic website (PHP) in a dedicated server , should I move to AWS, Is it financially viable?

Currently I am having a cost of $200/month for this. I am planing to host it in linux, medium type of instances.

Please advice me

Comment: What is your definition of low traffic? Have you thought about a vps?

Comment: If it's a low traffic site, why are you hosting on a dedicated site? Would shared hosting not be better?

Comment: shared host would not do better for sites functionality. We using $200 VPS hosting.

Comment: So you do NOT use a dedicated Server as you indicate in the question, which would mean your own HARDWARE.

Comment: CPU 5.94 GHZ, RAM 4435 MB, Disk Space 231 GB Bandwidth 3150 GB I need to be in AWS

Comment: how much traffic do you have per month?

Comment: Seriously? In most cases Amazon is way too expensive. I pay less than 200USD for a PHYSICAL server, 16gb ram, 4 cores + hyperthreading, 120gbssd+1000gb disc, 10tb traffic in chicago (and chicago is not a cheap location, but my machine needs to be close to Aurora facilities there). Your VPS price is way over the top.

Comment: @chewbakka It will less than < 5 GB

Comment: @TomTom Which is your hosting team ?

Comment: Team? You mean provider. I use swiftway. If you want to get LOW prices, go for server4you.com - i edited my answer with their offers. I am stuck in chicago, though - need max. 2ms to CME for my business side to work, so for me it is swiftway. My "team" is my own staff watching our business whenever we are active ;) I hate loosing money to technical glitches.

Comment: With 5GB a month i would go with shared hosting if this is technically an option.

Comment: @chewbakka unfortunately shared hosting is not an option for me

Answer (score 2):

Seriously? Amazon may be cheaper, but that starts with you totally overpaying to start with.

> CPU 5.94 GHZ, RAM 4435 MB, Disk Space 231 GB Bandwidth 3150 GB, this
>   is required

For 200 USD a month?

I pay around 180.

I have a quad core + hyperthreading machine, 16gb memory, 120gb ssd + 1000gb disc, 10000gb traffic. Location is in chicago, which is known to be an expensive location (I know one data cneter there charging more than 1000 USD per rack unit per month, 500 USD per hour) due to the financial side (Chicago Mercantile Exchange - tons of colocation needed for trading, which NEEDS to be close). Your requirements for 200 USD is already a LOT too expensive. You overpay. Significantly.

Generally AWS etc. does scale badly with price for base load. They are great for smaller stuff, they are great for "peak" stuff (fire up 100 machines for 3 hours, then drop them), but a constant 24/7 load scenario - the price goes through the roof.

TOI give you an idea what you would pay if you are not location bound....

Fujitsu PRIMERGY MX130 S1
AMD Athlon™ II Quad-Core
16 GB DDR3-RAM
2x 1,500 GB SATA II-HDD
Unlimited traffic

50 (!) USD. Well, 48.99.

Your 200 a month buy you there TWO of those:

OPteron 3280, 8x2,4ghz, 32gb ram, 2x2000gb sata drives, 100mbit flatrate. That is TWO of those, not one (price is 98.99 per month).

Really, you dont talk about "is AWS cheaper" but about "why do I overpay like I have no idea what servers cost".

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the usage of your instance. Yes, it may be more financially viable. But it depens.

You should have a look at this calculator provided by Amazon: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

It may help you identify your estimated costs per month.

Comment: thanks for sharing it, But I dont get understand what they are mentioning there.

Comment: CPU 5.94 GHZ, RAM 4435 MB, Disk Space 231 GB
Bandwidth 3150 GB, this is required